# Is there a way to find out the value of the three categories like light, medium and heavy on Android Studio's Energy Profiler?

Tags: android, android-profiler

Is there a way to find out the value of the three categories like light, medium and heavy on Android Studio's Energy Profiler? for example the light category, the battery energy used starts from 0 mah to 10 mah.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyRek.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind using light/medium/heavy instead of actual amperage numbers is to provide relative battery usage throughout the profiling session to help developers discover energy spikes and investigate potential performance bottlenecks. The way the battery usage is measured is a model built after a reference device (Pixel 2) and calculating CPU/network/GPS usage relative to that device. You can find the threshold in the Android Studio source code but the amperage numbers won't make much sense because they are all relative numbers.

Comment: im already check Android Studio Source Code, then i got this testing code, there is argument "value : 100", is it mean 100A (Amperage) or something else ? 
[![amparage.png](https://i.postimg.cc/wT0GdPZD/amparage.png)](https://postimg.cc/crtmRDsJ)

Comment: It's mA (mili Amps). See how it's calculated for Pixel 2: https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:transport-database/src/main/java/com/android/tools/datastore/energy/PowerProfile.java;l=89;drc=b36bf3d1f893bfaa2efc582c71d5a78fe3d6a88f. Then everything is modeled after Pixel 2 (e.g. energy usage is scaled by CPU frequency).